# Has any team won the country's top league (division) playing from temporary stadium?

Tags: football, trivia, history, venues

In the [Premier League](https://www.premierleague.com/) 2017/18, [Tottenham Hotspur F.C.](http://www.tottenhamhotspur.com/) are using the [Wembley Stadium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wembley_Stadium) as temporary home while their new stadium is being constructed.

So, I was wondering if they win the Premier League this season will they be the first team to do so playing from a temporary stadium in country's top league? And if they are not the first team to do so, which club have done this and when?

Answer (score 2):

A similar thing happened to [Qarabağ FK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qaraba%C4%9F_FK) (the first Azerbaijani team to make it to the group stage of the [UEFA Champions League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017%E2%80%9318_UEFA_Champions_League#Group_C)) in the [Azerbaijan Premier League 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_Azerbaijan_Top_League). After the home city of the club Aghdam was [attacked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Aghdam) in June 12, 1993 and later occupied in July 23, 1993 by Armenian military forces and Qarabağ's [home stadium "Imarat"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imarat_Stadium) was destroyed by bombardments, the team forced to move to the capital city Baku and eventually won the title in August 1, 1993.

Currently, the team is using ["Azersun Arena"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azersun_Arena) for league and cup games and the [Olympic Stadium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baku_Olympic_Stadium) for its European fixtures. Both stadiums are located in Baku.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Shakhtar Donetsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC_Shakhtar_Donetsk) who won the **Ukrainian championship in 2017, 2018 and 2019** by playing their home games in Lviv and Kharkiv while their main stadium is in Donetsk.
The "Donbass Arena" has been unavailable since 2014 due to the conflict in Crimea.